# In the android code base, where is the activity lifecycle defined?

Tags: android, code-search

I see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) documentation under `developer.android.com`, describing the Activity lifecycle. However, I am trying to match the description up with the actual android code, at `cs.android.com`, where the activity life cycle is actually defined.

Looking there in code search at [Activity.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java;l=1579;drc=master;bpv=0;bpt=1), I see, for example, the `onCreate` method defined. But I have not been able to find where this is actually *called* as part of the lifecycle. Maybe it is listed when I search for its references, but there are thousands of references, including a lot of overrides, and I have not found where it is called defining its place in the activity life cycle.

Where might I find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the below code to your main activity and run it while opening the logcat .The log massage will show you which method within the activity cycle has been called .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.v("MainActivity", "Oncreat");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v("MainActivity", "onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v("MainActivity", "onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("MainActivity", "onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v("MainActivity", "onStop");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    Log.v("MainActivity", "OnRestart");

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("MainActivity", "onDestroy");
}
```

You can also check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/activity-lifecycle-in-android-with-demo-app/) for more details .